# QRegExp for IP Address of QlineEDit in QT

Tags: qt, validation, qlineedit, qregexp, qregularexpression

How we can validate for QlineEdit control when i want to enter the IP Address into QlineEdit control, that control should be allow only IP address . don't allow any alphabets ,characters except dot(.) All the parts should be in range of 0-255

IP Address contain four parts and must three dots(.):
first part should contain 3 digits.(must)
second part should contain min 1 digit and max 3 digits..
third part should contain min 1 digit and max 3 digits.
four part should contain minimun 1 digit.

ex: 122.234.245.211
121.112.112.44
255.255.136.132
133.231.123.2
255.0.0.0
121.0.0.23

Below ADDRESS should not accept: should give errorMessage bOx

ex: 24.253.321.422
    442.445.552.444
23535.35.353.33
3532.333.332

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of **QRegExpValidator** class.
And regex as like this:

**[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}\\.[0-9]{1,3}**

After that use QLineEdit::setValidator () function to set validator.

Hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks a lot. but i need that every part of IP address should be in range of [0-255]